# How to install gRPC php extension on CentOS 7 CyberPanel

Tags: php, centos, grpc, cyber-panel

This is my first time using VPS Server I'm hosting a Laravel website, And I need PHP gRPC extension.

Server details:

```
hosting from: Hostinger VPS
OS: CentOS 7
control panel: CyberPanel 2.3
```

using server SSH I have installed gRPC on PHP81, but the website uses different PHP, I have to select the PHP version in the CyberPanal control panel for each Website, There is a PHP setting on CyberPanal but there are only 41 extensions I can install and uninstall using PHP81, I cannot add another extension.

[image: screen shot of php extensions there are no grpc]

I have tried installing using

```
sudo yum install lsphp81-pecl-grpc
```

result

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org
 * epel: atl.mirrors.knownhost.com
 * extras: mirror.atl.genesisadaptive.com
 * remi-php81: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
 * updates: mirrors.wcupa.edu
10 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package lsphp81-pecl-grpc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

in CLI there is gRPC using `php -m`

but in website using `phpinfo();` there is no gRPC

Is there any way I can add gRPC

Comment: Hi, Please refer [this article on cyberpanel community](https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/tutorial-how-to-install-any-php-modules-using-pear-package-manager/37785) to install packages that are not available. It is for 7.4 but you may  change the version and install........

Comment: Please check the official gRPC PHP README to see if any of the provided installation options work for you: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.53.0/src/php/README.md.